# Matching string that isn't wrapped with certain characters

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to make automatic tag detection and convertion into hyperlinks. Problem is, that it has to be done after the string is run through the following:

```
htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

Now, i.e., the `'` symbol is turned into `&#39;`. The tags are in the form of `#[a-Z0-9\-\_]`

So, the script considers the encoded special characters as tags because of the `#39` part.

How do I match with `preg_match` so, that it would not consider `#` marks preceded with `&` mark as tags?

Thank you!

Comment: Here's a tutorial: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html#11

Comment: Remember that "&" may be part of an url. Htmlspecialchars() change "&" to "&amp;" so the lookbehind suggestions below would still work reliably, but the url-matching will be more complicated. Maybe it's simpler to reverse htmlspecialchars, do your thing, and then redo htmlspecialchars (if you cannot get it before htmlspecialchars).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a **[lookbehind assertion](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php)** to check that the string is not preceded by a `&`:

Try with this:

```
"/(?<!&)#[\w-]+/"
```

The `(?<!&)` cause the `#` to match only if it is not preceded by `&`.

The `\w` part matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

You may also want to check if the tag is preceded by a whitespace or is a the start of the string:

```
"/(:?^|\s)#[\w-]+/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a **[Look Behind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**

> `(?<!a)b` matches a "b" that is not preceded by an "a"

In your case, that would be

```
(?<!&)#[a-Z0-9\-\_]
```

Will not match `#` preceded by `&`

Comment: Worked like a charm! There's always something new to learn :)